# Inverse for an linear application

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

> **Proposition.** Let $V$ and $W$ two vector spaces on field $\mathbb{K}$; we suppose that $V$ has finite dimension and that $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Then the application $$\mathcal{A}\colon \text{Hom}(V,W)\to W^n$$ that to every linear application $L\colon V\to W$ associates $\mathcal{A}(L)=(L(v_1),\dots, L(v_n))\in W^n$ is an isomorphism. In particular, if also the dimension of $W$ is finite then $$\dim\text{Hom}(V,W)=(\dim V)(\dim W).$$

*Proof.* I have just proved that the map $\mathcal{A}$ is injective and surjectiv, taking into account the fact that a linear application is fully defined once we know how it acts on the elements of a basis.

But I can't determine the inverse application of $\mathcal{A}$, can someone help me?

Comment: If you have shown that it is injective and surjective (and linear), then you have shown that it is an isomorphism. Why do you need to determine the inverse?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shown that it is injective and surjective (and linear), then you have shown that it is an isomorphism.

As for the inverse; for every $n$-tuple $(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\in W^n$, there is a unique linear map $L\in\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ such that $L(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i$.